# What var type you use on growing buffers

Tags: c, malloc

I need to read some bytes from a socket stream.
No i do a expanding buffer like this:

```
long curbufsize = 1024*24;
long expand = 1024*24;
void *buf = xmalloc(curbufsize);
void *buf_ptr_start = buf;

char mem[1024*24]; 
while (rc = my_read_from_stream(handle, mem, sizeof(men)) {
    len = (int)buf-((int)buf_ptr_start+rc);
    if(curbufsize < len) {
        curbufsize+=expand;
        xrealloc(buf_ptr_start, curbufsize);
    }
    memcpy(buf, mem, rc);
}
```

where should i use size_t and long/int? Should the buffersize be a size_t?
Should i better write for the new len calculation:

```
len = (size_t)buf-((size_t)buf_ptr_start+rc);
```

Any other optimization?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `int` this way is incorrect since `int` may be smaller than the pointer size of your system and will thus lead to truncation. I'd use `size_t` to keep track of your current buffer size and there's no need for any pointer arithmetic.

The reallocation is also completely broken. Why are you calling `xrealloc()` and then ignoring the return value. That's like a leaking version of `free()`!

You could write it something like this:

```
size_t len = 0;
size_t size = 0;
size_t expand = 1024*24;
char *buf = NULL;
char *newbuf;
char mem[1024*24]; 
while (rc = my_read_from_stream(handle, mem, sizeof(men)) {
    if (size < len+rc) {
        while (size < len+rc)
        {
            size += expand;
        }
        newbuf = xrealloc(buf, size);
        if (!newbuf)
        {
            free(buf);
            return ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED;
        }
        buf = newbuf;
    }
    memcpy(buf+len, mem, rc);
    len += rc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look in the header file that declares `xmalloc`; the type of its parameter must be right there. Though by the look of your code you are not trying to write a portable application, so you probably don't need to worry about such choices.

Just fix the bugs.

Edit: seeing that you talk about optimization, take into account that `int` might be faster than `size_t` (most probably it isn't) - profile the two variants and choose the fastest (or acknowledge that they have the same efficiency).